# File on the web server not updating in the browser - why?

Tags: linux, browser, website

I have updated a project web site on Sourceforge today and had a very strange behavior:

Clicking "reload" in the web browser (Waterfox 56.2.9 under Linux) did not show the modified page.

To debug the problem, I uploaded an additional file and opened it in the web browser. That worked. Then I deleted the file on the server and clicked "reload".

The same time I tried to load the deleted file as well as the modified file using the `wget` tool:

The `wget` tool loaded the modified file correctly and reported `Error 404` for the deleted file - just the way I expected it.

However, the web browser did *not* recognize that one file was modified and the other one was changed! This is what I have tested (*after* having tested `wget`):

- Clicking "reload" for both the deleted and the modified file
- Clearing the entire "recent history"
  ("Time range: Everything", all options (Cache, Cookies, ...) selected)
- Closing the web browser and re-opening it
- Re-booting the computer and re-starting the web browser
- Clearing the entire "recent history" again
- Opening the deleted and the modified file in the web browser again
- At this point the web browser was *still showing* the old version of the modified file and it was *still showing* the deleted file!
- Starting `wireshark`
- Clicking "reload" in the web browser
- Finally, the web browser was showing me the updated version of the modified file and an error message when trying to open the deleted file.

**Can anybody explain me what's going on here?**

I have two suspicions:

- The web browser does not use its own cache but it uses some "external" caching mechanism (for example some Linux-wide caching mechanism) which is not cleared when I perform a "clear history"
  (I have this suspicion after observing the browser with `strace -e openat ...`)
- The web server has some internal cache and the web server behaves differently depending on the client (`wget` or the browser) used

(I suspect that starting `wireshark` had no influence on the web browser behavior.)

If my *first* suspicion should be true:

How can I really clear the cache?

How can I force the browser to re-load the web site?

Comment: Which browser? Have you cleared its cache?

Comment: @harrymc In my question I wrote: "Waterfox 56.2.9 under Linux"; as you can read in the section "This is what I have tested", I tried to clear the cache however I suspect that the browser uses some second cache which is not cleared if I select "clear cache" in the "clear recent history" dialog box.

Comment: Try another browser. If the problem disappears, then this is a Waterfox problem. If it stays, then the problem might not be in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it caused me a lot of strife.  Updates to existing files would take hours, and in the meantime my website would be partially broken!  It was especially noticeable for CSS files.  Interestingly enough, it happened on my root domain, but not on my test subdomain.

After much arduous pulling of hair, my website host technical support led me to "Performance Caching" which was enabled by default.  Basically, they, by default, cache all of the web pages on their end to speed things up at the expense of pages being up-to-date.

It is possible to turn off but unfortunately not for CSS files!  Anyway, the workaround is to clear the cache, which takes a few minutes to propagate, but that's not too bad considering.  I went into my hosting provider's web portal (which is based at sucuri.net) and found a way to do this.  It may be different for you, but here is what I did:

Security > Firewall > Performance > Advanced Settings > Caching

From here I could see that caching was happening and could also configure it and, most importantly, clear the cache.  After this, my new updates propagated and then my website was happy again!